# SharePoint Foundation 2010 connect to Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, active-directory

So I have an application built in SharePoint Foundation 2010. Until now the application users, were Windows users. But suddenly the necessity for a LDAP authentication arose.

Since I have the application configured with windows users and windows authentication, I was told that the best way to accomplish this was to make a connection to an active directory and configure the LDAP on it.

I have few, to no knowledge of how active directory works.

So could you give some tips on how I should configure the AD and how I can connect it's users to my SharePoint application?

Also if you could also give some tips on how to configure LDAP on the AD I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement FBA in your sharepoint site to get users from Active Directory.

Please refer these link and perform given settings for FBA.

- [FBA](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/sharepoint-2010-form-based-authentication-using-active-directory/)
- [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/01/07/setting-up-fba-claims-in-sharepoint-2010-with-active-directory-membership-provider.aspx)

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without changing the authentication mode to fba? The client does not want fba.

Comment: As far as i know there is no other way because you want to use here LDAP.For more clarity go through this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288475(v=office.14).aspx ,       http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/05/06/configuring-claims-and-forms-based-authentication-for-use-with-an.aspx